# Python: queue to avoid database deadlocks?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, queue, python-asyncio

I've the function `add_item(item)` which is called from 5 different services, randomly (event-based) every few seconds, sometimes at the same time, which can result into **database deadlocks**.

I was thinking about changing `add_item(item)` into `queue_item_for_creation(item)` and then add another service which calls `work_queue()`, which stores the queued items.

Is that a common pattern? If so, how is it called? Which libraries are recommended for something like that? Does asyncio help?

It's **not opinion-based**, because I'm asking for the common solution to a common issue.

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. You need to figure out why you're getting deadlocks. You may need to revisit how and when you lock database entities.

Comment: @dim Thanks for your reply. I've to optimize queries of course, but that's another topic. I'm currently looking for a way to reduce the concurrent writing operations, by bundling them.